# How to embed svg in a node with ''meimaid .js" with no space between the arrow and the image?

Tags: html, svg, mermaid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zKEd.png)

```
var mermaidAPI = mermaid.mermaidAPI;
mermaidAPI.initialize({
  startOnLoad:false
});
var element = document.getElementById("app");
var insertSvg = function(svgCode, bindFunctions){
  element.innerHTML = svgCode;
};
var graphDefinition = `graph LR; Systemstart-->SomeIcon(<img src='https://iconscout.com/ms-icon-310x310.png' width='40' height='40'/>);
var graph = mermaidAPI.render("mermaid", graphDefinition, insertSvg);`
```

this is how i enbed an image, but i woder how to change the image to svg format like this

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="68" height="68">
<rect x="10" y="10" height="48" width="48" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="param(color) red">
</rect>
<rect x="29" y="0" height="10" width="10" fill="black"></rect>
<text x="24" y="46" fill="param(text) black" style="font-size:32px;"
  content-value="param(number) 1">1</text>
<script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="param.js" /> 
</svg>
```

the rect and space between the image and arrow should not exists